# Wix iFrame always gets "Secured Connection Failed"

Tags: html, iframe, velo

I've added an HTML iFrame in Wix (like many many times before) and it always gets a "Secured Connection Failed" error with code: SEC_ERROR_REVOKED_CERTIFICATE
Even with the simplest code that does nothing.

[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/K0XKf.png)

Has anyone else got this? Any workaround?

Comment: I think this might be connected to CA root certificate being expired. See here: https://support.sectigo.com/articles/Knowledge/Sectigo-AddTrust-External-CA-Root-Expiring-May-30-2020. A lot of companies are affected. I think wix has to fix this at their end.

Comment: Yeah, I figured. They have also changed the HTML iFrame element URL which messed with my Google Maps credentials. I hope this doesn't happen a lot.